# Embedding data inside a c++ application

Tags: c++, cross-platform

Is there a platform-independent method to embed file data into a c++ program? For instance, I am making a game, and the levels are stored in text format. But I don't want to distribute those text files with the game itself. What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been [asked here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72616/embed-data-in-a-c-program). Basically, you just name the data with an accessible symbol. I like this method best:

> You can always write a small program or script to convert your text file into a header > > file and run it as part of your build process.

Answer (score 1):

You can always put the text in the code.  Say, for example, as an array of Strings or array of pointers to characters.

```
String txt[] = {
  "My first line.\n",
  "My second line.\n"
}
```

Of course there are better structures in the standard libraries, but in any case you put the text in a source file.

You could also consider putting the text into the package and encrypting it, if you're worried about people accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

If the levels are really stored simply as text, you could just declare static char arrays in your source:

```
static const char level1[] = "abcdeabcdeabcde....";
```

You can compile and link this right into your application and reference it just like any other variable.