# git keyword expansion after commit

Tags: git, filter, commit

I am using keyword expansion like the one described in the book [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion). However, after a commit one needs to do, for example,

```
rm file
git checkout file
```

to have the correct keyword expansion in the working files (since smudge is applied only after checkout).

How do I make the keyword expansion happen automatically also after a commit?

Of course, I could use a hook for the remove/re-checkout, but that does not seem to be a nice solution. Moreover I would have to check manually, which file was commited.

Is there a more elegant way? Can I, for instance, let run the smudge of a filter automatically after commit?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I make the keyword expansion happen automatically also after a commit?

You don't, that is why Git doesn't "really" support keyword expansion, as I detail in "[Git equivalent of subversion's `$URL$` keyword expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2059393/6309)".

An alternative (listed in  "[Git hook, modify commit files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14641656/6309)") is to use [`git notes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) to attach metadata to a commit (without modifying its SHA1).

Comment: I understand the Git philosophy on not having keyword expansion. I am using "git svn" (for writing tex-documents). I'm having keyword expansion when working with subversion directly; it is used to add a revision number to a printed out pdf for referencing. Therefore, I want to have it in my git-world as well.

Comment: @DanielKrenn I understand. I would recommend `git notes` to add *any* information you want to a commit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a post-commit hook would indeed solve your problem.

Add the following post-commit hook:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    BRANCH=$( git branch | awk 'sub(/^\*[[:space:]]+/,""){print;exit}' )
    git show --name-only -z --format= |
            xargs -r0 git reset "${BRANCH:-master}" --
```