# how to include git commit-number into a c++ executable?

Tags: c++, git, makefile

i use git as a version tracker for my c++ project.

sometimes i need to repeat a calculation and i would like to know which version of the program i used.

what would be a good way to put a # of the commit into the main executable? in other words. i'd like the program to tell me the # of the current commit in an introductory message as i run the program.

one way i can think of is to make the c++ program lunch "git log" from shell and extract the commit # but i'm not sure how to do it during make.

(I use linux)

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704907/how-can-i-get-my-c-code-to-automatically-print-out-its-git-version-hash

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to add to your makefile a rule to generate a .c file with the current git commit ID:

```
gitversion.c: .git/HEAD .git/index
    echo "const char *gitversion = \"$(shell git rev-parse HEAD)\";" > $@
```

Now simply add `gitversion.c` to your build process as normal. Make sure to remove it on `make clean`, and add it to `.gitignore` so it's not added to the git repository accidentally. Add an `extern const char *gitversion;` to a header somewhere, and you can access it like that.

Comment: 1) i'm not that familiar with make or git. i tried a quick search but still couldn't understand the part ".git/HEAD .git/index".

Comment: The files listed after `gitversion.c:` are the files it depends on. `.git` is a hidden directory; `HEAD` is a file in there. Therefore, when `.git/HEAD`or `.git/index` changes, `gitversion.c:` is rebuilt using the command on the next line.

Comment: Yes; this isn't entirely complete, mind you; it might be better to also reference .git/packed-refs and all files under .git/refs...

Comment: 2) i think i misunderstood smtn. here is what i do: 1. put those 2 lines in the Makefile after main.o rule. 2. include the line "extern const char *gitversion;" into main.cc. 3. put cout << *gitversion; into main.cc 4. run make. there is no gitversion.c in the directory (it's not created). i also get an error "main.cc:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `gitversion'"     did i miss something?

Comment: You need to actually reference gitversion.c from your link rule as you would any other .c file.

Comment: ok, most of it works now. but when i "git rev-parse HEAD" within makefile, it doesn't produce anything but it works perfect from bash. (git describe gives an error, so i use rev_parse)

Comment: What error does git describe give? It could be the same problem. Also make sure it's running in the right directory...

Comment: > git describe           
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
               ; it's in the same directory. in the makefile i have 'echo "const char *gitversion = \"$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)\";" > $@'. the first line of the make output is 'echo "const char *gitversion = \"\";" > gitversion.c'. cat gitversion.c gives 'const char *gitversion = "";'. however if i run in bash 'echo "const char *gitversion = \"$(git rev-parse HEAD)\";"', i get 'const char *gitversion = "00d768cf9fc6d3c6c78dd91dbb42c46fc43b6285";'

Comment: @kirill_igum let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/988/discussion-between-bdonlan-and-kirill-igum)

Comment: thanks to @bdonlan instead of $(git rev-parse HEAD), use $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis - no, that version is far inferior as unlike this it only updates when explicitly cleaned.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Good point. Relevant to note that this one updates only after committing new changes. Uncommitted changes result in `make` reporting that `gitversion.c` "is up to date". So running `make clean` may still be required.

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis I usually put the check directly into my link rule for that reason, and often feed the compiler source on its command line so there isn't even a .c file on disk.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for outlining an approach to avoid this issue.

Comment: This is probably obvious, but this is not cross platform, you'll need some tweaking to make this work on windows.

Answer (score 16):

I do the following in CMakeLists.txt:

```
IF(EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.git)
  FIND_PACKAGE(Git)
  IF(GIT_FOUND)
    EXECUTE_PROCESS(
      COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} rev-parse --short HEAD
      WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE "kml2maps_BUILD_VERSION"
      ERROR_QUIET
      OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
    MESSAGE( STATUS "Git version: ${kml2maps_BUILD_VERSION}" )
  ELSE(GIT_FOUND)
    SET(kml2maps_BUILD_VERSION 0)
  ENDIF(GIT_FOUND)
ENDIF(EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.git)

CONFIGURE_FILE(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/kml2mapsVersion.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/kml2mapsVersion.h @ONLY)
```

So the `git rev-parse --short HEAD`'s output is good to build in the binary.

Comment: This approach assumes that you run cmake manually for each commit.

Comment: And to get it working you need to define something like:
`#define GIT_REVISION "@kml2maps_BUILD_VERSION@"`
in `kml2mapsVersion.h.in`.

Comment: This article "CMake: Use Git Branch & Commit Details in Project" explains the cmake mechanism in more detail: http://xit0.org/2013/04/cmake-use-git-branch-and-commit-details-in-project

Answer (score 14):

I use `git describe` to get a version which either uses a tag or commit number. This usually gives nice versions like: `v0.1-1-g787c667` if the tip of the branch has additional commits above the 'v0.1' tag.

The git command I use is: `git describe --tags --always`. I usually use it with the SCons build system and define it as a constant, relevant parts of the SConstruct:

```py
import os, sys 
from subprocess import *

def getGitDesc():   
  return Popen('git describe --tags --always', stdout=PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read ().strip ()

GIT_DESC = getGitDesc () 
print "Building " + getGitDesc () + ".." 
env = Environment ()

# set up environment 
env.Append (CPPDEFINES = { 'GIT_DESC' : ('\\"%s\\"' % GIT_DESC) } )

# build your program
env.Program (....)
```

In the C or C++ program I can now access `GIT_DESC` as a string-constant:

```cpp
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
  cout << "Version: " << GIT_DESC << endl;
  return 42;
}
```

note: the `--abbrev=N` argument to `git describe` might be useful to achieve consistent version output independent of a users git configuration.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Qt, put this in your project's .pro file:

```
win32:DEFINES += GIT_BIN='C:\\Git\\bin\\git'
# or 'C:\\Progra~1\\Git\\bin\\git' - ymmv with putting spaces in here
win32:DEFINES += GIT_REVISION='\\"$$system($${GIT_BIN} rev-parse --short HEAD)\\"'
unix:DEFINES += GIT_REVISION='\\"$$system(git rev-parse --short HEAD)\\"'
```

Then use `GIT_REVISION` in your code as in the other answers - it behaves as `const char *`.

(Thanks to Alexander Barthel, who I plundered this tip from.)

Comment: It's easier to just manually add the `-D` flag to the list of compiler flags: `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DGIT_COMMIT=\"$(shell git describe --abbrev=4 --dirty --always --tags)\"`