# Embedded resources in Win32 Application

Tags: winapi, embedded-resource

I have embedded an EXE as a resource in my Win32 application.

I'm looking to the registry for a certain value. If the value is there and correct, then i copy the embedded EXE to the local file system an execute it from there.

I don't want it to be extracted from my EXE.

Should i do anything to prevent this, or is it impossible already?

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably mark an answer as correct and upvote all of the answers that were of help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but you could inbed the exe as an .obj or an static array rather than as a resource.  That would make it harder for an attacker to find in your code, but still not impossible.

You can use the unix objcopy tool to convert your exe into a .obj file and then link to that in your c code.  someone would have to decompile your code in order to find the .exe, which is quite a bit harder than using a resource extractor.

[Embed data in a C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72616/embed-data-in-a-c-program)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is impossible, and in fact it is quite easy to strip resources out of an executable. Here's the [first link](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html) from a Google search, for example. On the other hand you're already stripping the exe out and saving it to a file on the user's system, anybody sophisticated enough to find the embedded resource will also be able to find your extracted file. I wouldn't spend too much time worrying about it.

Comment: You're right. "Impossible" was a harsh word :) How about storing the resource as encrypted and decrypt it before executing? And a bonus: could it be executed without exporting to the local file system?

Comment: Nope. You'll have to store the key someplace. If the attacker has enough time and patience, he'll find it for sure.
(And yes, I'm fairly sure you could execute the EXE from memory)

Comment: Although it is possible, it seems it's not an easy task. http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=383351&PageSize=25

Answer (score 0):

I have to secure an application. I can't modify the application. All i can do is writing small utilities around it, like creating an online serial system, unique hardware information hash storing, a loader exe etc.

But now i see that my intentions are almost useless without modifying the original applications. I'd be apprecieted any help on this.

Comment: Reading this again, perhaps i should create a new question from this :)