# How to get the bytes of a file?

Tags: c++, c, bitarray

Simple question I know, what I want to do is be able to get the bytes of a file to use to add those bytes to an bit array, which I can then use to write to a file named `bytes.exe` and launch it. I know how to read the bytes of an existing file at runtime. But I don't know how to get the bytes of a file to copy and paste into my `bitarray[]` at design time.

The goal is to be able to write the bites of `bitarray[]` to `myfile.exe` at runtime, and then launch said file. There are many `bitarray[]'s` I'll be using, based on many different file types, so I'm looking for an easy method.

Is there some kind of decompiler that should be used? I just looked into resource scripts, but I don't want to attach any dependencies to my main .exe.

Comment: What's wrong with explicitly copying the file? Is there a reason you're attempting to move bytes around manually?

Comment: You mean copying the file at design time? How do I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by "design time"?

Comment: While I am writing code. Before compiling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which program creates a C array given any file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155578/which-program-creates-a-c-array-given-any-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting Windows, the easiest way to do this is to embed `myfile.exe` as a resource, then load the resource at runtime and create a file and write the contents of the resource to your new file.

If you can't use resources, then you'll need to create a source file (.c or .h) that initializes a byte array with the contents of `myfile.exe` and include that as part of your build.  Check out this answer for one possible approach:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73653/333127

**EDIT**: After further review, I don't think the source code in the link I referenced above will work for binary input files.  Here's a quick alternative I just threw together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BYTES_PER_LINE 70

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp;
    int ch;
    int numBytes = 0;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: tobytes <file>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("char fileContents[] = {\n");
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (numBytes > 0)
            printf(",");

        ++numBytes;
        if (numBytes % BYTES_PER_LINE == 0)
            printf("\n");

        printf("0x%x", ch);
    }
    printf("\n};\n");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice one. I just though there would be a program that does this already. I guess I'll publish mine if there isn't one already.

Comment: Can I use the source to publish my new program, ExeEmbedder © ? (Joking 50%)

Comment: If you have vim installed, you can run `xxd -i thefile` to do the same

Comment: @nos: I didn't know about `xxd` until now -- thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @ cbranch, thanks for that code. Looks good, will let you know if I have any probs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you want to do, but why not write a small program that reads a file and translates it into a C array.

That is if the file data is:

```
01 02 03 04 (binary)
```

The program will generate a file that is:

```
char data[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04};
```

and then run this program as a prebuild step of your application (in your Makefile or whatever build system you are using), and generate the output into your source tree.

In that way the data would be compiled into your application and be available statically.

As I said, I'm not clear if this is the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yeah, sweet. I considered this approach, but I just thought I might have already been done. I tried to google for a program that does this, but had no luck. Which surprised me, cause I  thought this would be relatively common.

Comment: This sort of thing is generally called "Resources" and "Resource Compilers", where data files are bundled into applications through various mechanisms. Each platform does it differently.  What I describe is the simplest approach with the fewest features.

Comment: Thanks, I'll google around those keywords. All I need is to get they bytes of program "abc.exe" and put it into myprog.exe as a byte array,  and wtite the program to a new byte array as newprog.exe at runtime.

Comment: Oh and I know it might sound like I am trying to steal intellectual property, this is not the case :D